Shadows flickering in Blender 4.2 and 4.3 eevee
Shadows flicker in the eevee-next video renderings. I made a simple test scene to demonstrate the issue. Blend file and example videos attached to this post. Basically a sun light lights through a transparent material (a glass panel) into the scene. To make it more noticeable I added multiple sun lights to create overlapping shadows that flicker as camera pans, the shadows flicker.
Here's a video rendered in 3.6, no flickering. All good:
https://streamable.com/tv14jb
Here's the same scene rendered in 4.3 beta. Result is similar in 4.2. Notice the flickering shadows that are easy to see at the end. Shadows typically flicker when the camera moves:
https://streamable.com/3y59nm
Blend file:


Anyone has any guesses on this one? What causes the shadows to flicker in the second video (4.2). Issue is not present in the first video (3.6)

I was facing the same issue Using 4.3.1
https://streamable.com/9riarj
What solved the problem for me was increasing que shadow memory usage:

